# How to prove $ B^2 \leq 2AC$ using other inequality?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I proved that $ C(x^2) - 2Bx + 2A \geq  0$  is true for all $x.$

How can I show that
$B^2 \leq 2AC
$
?

How do I find an $x$?

I know that $A, B , C $ are non-negative.

thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question? I can find many $X$'s, but I don't know what equation your $X$ must satisfy!

Comment: I need to show that B2≤2AC

I saw an answer that say that if we take
 x=squre(2AC)/C 
and place it in C(x2)−2Bx+2A≥0 it will work. 

but how can I find this X... how did they find it? @PatrickDaSilva

Comment: What if $A=C=0$ and $B = 1$? Isn't this inequality false? I'm concerned about all those answers I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

$$Cx^2 - 2Bx + 2A \geq  0\to \frac1c(x^2-\frac{2B}{c}x+\frac{2A}{C})= \frac1c((x-\frac{B}{C})^2-\frac{B^2}{c^2}+\frac{2A}{c})\ge0\to$$$$\frac1c(x-\frac{B}{C})^2-\frac{B^2}{c}+\frac{2A}{1}\ge0\to -\frac{B^2}{c}+\frac{2A}{1}\ge0\to B^2 \leq 2AC$$
 easily you can find   close interval that $ x$ is in this interval

Answer (score 0):

if $A = 0$ then it's trivial. if it's not then it's quadratic with respect to $x$. calculate the $\Delta$ of this function - if $Cx^2 - 2Bx + 2A \geq 0$ for all $x$ then the $\Delta$ has to be non-positive which gives the desired result.
oh, and what $x$ do you want to find?

Comment: I need to show that $B^2 \leq 2AC$
I saw an answer that say that if we take

 x=squre(2AC)/C
and place it in  $ C(x^2) - 2Bx + 2A \geq 0$ it will work.
but how can I find this X... how did they find it?

and thanks for your solution. it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=Cx^2-2Bx+2A$

If $C=0$ then the iequality is trivial so let $C\ne 0$

Then $f'(x)=2Cx-2B$

As $f(x)$ is a quadratic function which is always greater than or equal to $0$ so there exists an unique minimum of $f$ (say at $x_0$)

Then $f'(x_0)=0\Rightarrow x_0=\frac{B}{C}$

But $f(x_0)\ge 0\Rightarrow f(x_0)=\frac{B^2}{C}-2\frac{B^2}{C}+2A\ge 0\Rightarrow \frac{B^2}{C}\le 2A\Rightarrow B^2\le 2AC$